# DRYly represent a list of settings objects

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I'm sketching out a Django model that has a few different boolean fields:

```
video_enabled = models.BooleanField()
audio_enabled = models.BooleanField()
sensors_enabled = models.BooleanField()
backup_enabled = models.BooleanField()
```

I have a number of different 'modes' that have different settings involving these booleans. I'd like to store the 'defaults' for these modes in some kind of dictionary structure so I can easily reset the settings model to a default state based on what mode I want to restore it to. To store those settings, I've been doing something like this:

```
SETTINGS = { 
    'mode_1': {
        'video': True,
        'audio': True,
        'sensor': True,
        'backup': True
    }
    'mode_2': {
         'video': False,
         'audio': False,
    .... etc. .....
```

As the number of modes grows, this obviously gets really repetitive.

Is there a nicer, DRYer design pattern that could represent this in Python? I was thinking enums, but I kind of don't want to get locked into an ordered sequence that every component needs to know about in order to communicate with the django server.

Comment: Do you need those individual booleans for other requirements?  Seems like an alternative to your current design would be to have a single field with one valid value per mode.  Then elsewhere in your code you could define functions video(), audio() etc. that returned booleans; each would return true only if the mode is one where that boolean applied.

Comment: The settings in the dictionaries are just defaults. A user will be able to customize the modes (updating in the db level) as they choose one by one or all at once. So I definitely need the individual fields.

Comment: Are you looking for a DRYer way of building that `SETTINGS` dictionary,  or a completely different pattern to solve the repetitiveness?

Comment: The settings dictionary. The other stuff isn't that repetitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to always repeat the same keys put them into a list:

```
keys = ['audio', 'video', 'sensor', 'backup']

SETTINGS = {
    'mode_1': dict.fromkeys(keys, True),
    'mode_2': dict.fromkeys(keys, False),
}
```

If the default settings may different values then you can still avoid repeating the keys using `zip` to build the dicts:

```
SETTINGS = {
    'mode_3': dict(zip(keys, [True, False, False, True])),
}
```

In fact you could specify the values for each mode and then build the dictionary in a dict comprehension:

```
import itertools as it
keys = ['audio', 'video', 'sensor', 'backup']

SETTINGS_LIST = (
    ('mode_1', it.repeat(True)), 
    ('mode_2', it.repeat(False)), 
    ('mode_3', [True, False, False, True]),
)

SETTINGS = {mode: dict(zip(keys, values)) for mode, values in SETTINGS_LIST}
```

This doesn't do any repetition of value or key literal and `dict` and `zip` are called only in one place.